# Select Attribute value and field value Using jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have multiple input field like this

```
<input type="text" name="loksabha" data-name="loksabha" class="form-control lokVidhan" placeholder="Loksabha"><br><br>

<input type="text" name="zila" data-name="zila" class="form-control lokVidhan" placeholder="Zila">

<script>
    $('.lokVidhan').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            var name = $.trim(request.term);
            var data_name = $('.lokVidhan').attr('data-name');
            console.log(data_name);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I want  to select current field value using:

```
var name = $.trim(request.term);
```

which is working fine, but  I also want to select:

```
var data_name = $('.lokVidhan').attr('data-name');`
```

but it's only giving me the first field value. I want current field value. I also try this:

```
var data_name = $(this).val(); // result:  undefined
```

Comment: Thak you Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each()` so that you can preserve the context inside a variable with each iteration like

```
 $('.lokVidhan').each(function() {
             var that = $(this);
             that.autocomplete({
                 source: function(request, response) {
                     var name = $.trim(request.term);
                     var data_name = that.attr('data-name');
                     console.log(data_name);
                 }
             });
```